# Cannot connect java debugger

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

In Domino Designer 9 I try to debug a Java agent, for this i followed this steps:
http://www.bizzybee.be/2013/01/11/debugging-java-code-in-domino-designer-8-5-or-9/

I have as port : 8000

In my commandprompt if I do netstat -a I can see that port 0.0.0.0:8000 is LISTENING.
In my notes ini i have the following:

```
JavaEnableDebug=1
JavascriptEnableDebug=1
JavaDebugOptions=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

Or sometimes I only put

```
JavaEnableDebug=1
```

But I keep getting the error Server connection failed:

[image]

How can I connect the debugger??